# Use of php within an html file and the position of the html file within a directory

Tags: php, html, relative-path, require

I am new to php, so please assume I know nothing!

I have a website in which I want to use "require" to add a header and footer to each page. I'm assuming this is the best way to allow me the flexibility to change the header file and automatically have all pages that include it update.
The index, header and many other files are in the root directory. Using:

```
<?php require("header.php"); ?>
```

work fine for all pages located in the root directory.

But I am having trouble using the same process for an html file located within (e.g.) root/sub-directory/example.html. Using the above code does nothing. The header is not included, which I first assumed was to do with incorrect reference to the header file from the sub-directory. I have tried reading about different methods of referencing to no avail, but I now wonder if that might not be the problem I'm having here: I have noticed that I do not even get an error associated with not finding the header file (the reason why I used require initially). It appears as though the above code within the html file in the sub-directory is completely ignored by the browser. (It is worth noting that all of the other text is read correctly and references out of the sub-dir seem to be working).

Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: Try adding "../" in the beginning of your require.

Comment: are you trying to do the require from inside the html file?

Answer (score 0):

PHP code will only be processed if the file format is .php, so change that and it should work.